# Akka persistentChannel does not delete message from Journal upon confirm

Tags: scala, persistence, akka

I am writing a piece of code that uses PersistentChannel to send a message to an actor that does some IO. Upon completion it confirms the  ConfirmablePersistent message.
The document says that upon confirmation the message shall be deleted in a PersistentChannel. But in my case my files stays in the journal with out getting deleted.
My requirement is that as soon as I get a successful result for the IO or the deadline has exceeded the persisted message should be deleted from the journal.

```
class IOWorker(config: Config, ref: ActorRef) 
    extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  import IOWorker._
  val channel = context.actorOf(PersistentChannel.props(
      PersistentChannelSettings(redeliverInterval = 1.minute, 
           pendingConfirmationsMax = 1,pendingConfirmationsMin = 0)))  
  val doIOActor = context.actorOf(DOIOActor(config))    
  def receive = {
      case payload @ (msg, deadline)=> 
        channel ! Deliver(Persistent(payload), doIOActor.path)
  }
}

object DOIOActor {  
  def apply(config: Config) = Props(classOf[DOIOActor], config)
}
class DOIOActor(config: Config) extends Actor 
    with ActorLogging {

  def receive = {
    case p @ ConfirmablePersistent(payload, sequenceNr, redeliveries) =>      
      payload match {
          case (msg, deadline: Deadline) => 
            deadline.hasTimeLeft match {
              case false => p.confirm()
              case true =>              
                sender ! SAVED(msg)
                Try{DOIO}
                match 
                {
                  case Success(v) =>
                    sender ! SUCCESS(msg)
                    p.confirm()
                  case Failure(doioException) => 
                    log.warning(s"Could not complete DOIO. $doioException")
                    throw doioException
                }
      }
  }

}
  def DOIO(ftpClient: FTPClient, destination: String, file: AISData) = {    
    SOMEIOTASK match {
      case true => log.info(s"Storing file to $destination.")
      case false => 
        throw new Exception(s"Could not DOIO to destination $destination")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Deletions are performed asynchronously by most journal implementations, as discussed [on the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/akka-user/_d9gpIJyKe0/B6Ie_axaFQMJ).

Comment: I have a process that is running since last Sunday evening using the above code base. The journal space has grown to be around 24 GB so far. I am still continuing my run to see when the compaction will happen and the "marked deleted" messages will be physically deleted. The only way my code is different than Martin Krasser's example is that my message has the size of 8 MB. Could that be playing some role?

Comment: Please find a runnable project that demonstrates the problem [here](https://github.com/manasdebashiskar/akkapersistenceExample)